# Python precision of math.pi

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I was coding in python and found a strange bug :

```
import math
print(math.tan(math.pi/4) == 1)
```

Prints False, as math.tan(math.pi / 4) is 0.9999999999...

Do you know why Python exhibits such behaviour ? I mean, if there is a reason other than precision issues ?

Thanks !

Comment: Precision Error is really most likely

Comment: Print `math.pi` to a thousand decimals. Look up the value of π on the Internet (http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/PI-10000.html ). Compare.

Comment: This may be the most common question on stackoverflow. See the [floating-point tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info) for details why one should not compare floating-point values with `==`,

Comment: As far as floating point arithmetic goes, that's as close as you're going to get. This is why floats are usually compared with a tolerance: `abs(math.tan(math.pi/4) - 1) < 0.000001`

Comment: Value of `math.pi`: http://ideone.com/7oYuR8

Comment: @phihag I don't think that “0.1 is not represented exactly in binary floating-point” and “π is not represented exactly in binary floating-point” are exactly the same, and neither proposition imply that one should not compare floating-point values for `==`.

Comment: This is neither a bug nor specific to Python. http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: @PascalCuoq - the only difference is that one-tenth can be represented in some bases while π cannot be represented exactly in *any* integer base (yes, the base-π representation would be "1").

Comment: @chepner You mean `10`. One is one in any base.

Comment: Oops, yeah. (I almost wrote "0.1" initially; I guess I didn't shift the pi point far enough :)

Comment: See these approximate equalities: double(pi)=pi-1.2e-16 , double(pi/4)=pi/4-3e-17 , tan(pi/4+e)=1+2e , tan(double(pi/4))=1-6e-17 so 0.9999999999999999 is really the nearest double to the tangent of nearest double to pi/4. I'd say, Python is using a math library that performs quite well in this case.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: but why digits of Pi [here](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/PI-10000.html) and [here](http://ideone.com/7oYuR8) are different? See also [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue3365) in the Python issue tracker.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Python uses the IEEE 754 double-precision format, which has 53 bits of precisions. That usually allow to represent between 15 and 17 significant decimal digits correctly. You cannot take an arbitrary irrational number and expect to represent all its decimal exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is R FAQ 7.31 translated into Python:

http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_82.html

That example in python gives the same result:

```
>>> a = math.sqrt(2)
>>> a*a - 2
4.440892098500626e-16
```

The difference in your tangent example is also very, very small:

```
>>> math.tan(math.pi/4) - 1
-1.1102230246251565e-16
```

and is just accumulated through all the floating point operations involved in dividing by four and taking the tan of an angle.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the precision error as it is very obvious. However if you want to get the relevant value of Pi then you can use this(Also know as Archimedes method):

```
import math

# max error allowed
eps = 1e-10

# initialize w/ square
x = 4
y = 2*math.sqrt(2)

ctr = 0
while x-y > eps:
    xnew = 2*x*y/(x+y)
    y    = math.sqrt(xnew*y)
    x    = xnew
    ctr += 1

print("PI = " + str((x+y)/2))
print("# of iterations = " + str(ctr))
```

Comment: This isn't going to be any more precise than the value already stored in `math.pi`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the good ways to solve this is to implement custom function isEqual, which will compare two numbers with specified delta as

```
DELTA = 0.0001

def isEqual(number1, number2)
  if (number1 - DELTA) < number2 or (number1 + DELTA) > number2 # as example and demonstration of the idea
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a fairly terrible idea. :-) Apart from the minor facts that the function is misnamed (since it doesn't compute equality at all), the name violates PEP8, and the logic in the body of the function is wrong (you want an `and`, not an `or`), the main problem is that an appropriate choice of `DELTA` (which should be a function argument, by the way) depends *hugely* on context, and in many contexts it's not appropriate to do an absolute error comparison with a `DELTA` at all.  A hard-coded `DELTA` of `0.0001` is virtually useless.